# не получается сравнить строки C#

Tags: c#, строки

не получается сравнить строки, не проходит условие if

```
String[] tokenList = postfixExpr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for(int i = 0; i < tokenList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(tokenList[i].Equals('1') || tokenList[i].Equals('2') || tokenList[i].Equals('3') || tokenList[i].Equals('4') || tokenList[i].Equals('5') || tokenList[i].Equals('6') || tokenList[i].Equals('7') || tokenList[i].Equals('8') || tokenList[i].Equals('9') || tokenList[i].Equals('0'))
                        operandStack.Push(Int32.Parse(tokenList[i]));
```

[image: значение в tokenList]

[image: результат сравнения]

Comment: Меня смущает, что вы `string` сравниваете с `char`. Хотя на `Equals` это вроде бы не должно влиять. Но всё-таки попробуйте двойные кавычки, а не одиночные. И попробуйте код вашей `7` напечатать и код символа в `tokenList[0]`.

Comment: `tokenList[i] == "1"`. А вообще, как по мне, у вас очень странный код, допустим его можно переписать так: `if ("0123456789".Contains(tokenList[i])){ ... }`, и тут мы понимаем, что вы смотрите, является это цифрой, а для таких проверок существует `char.IsDigit()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ во блин, а я и не подумал что он ищет является ли символ цифрой. Вообще на автомате просто переписал в массив)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] valuesArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];

String[] tokenList = postfixExpr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for(int i = 0; i < tokenList.Length; i++)
{
    if( Array.IndexOf(valuesArr, tokenList[i]) > -1 ) {
        operandStack.Push(Int32.Parse(tokenList[i]));
    }
    // если не сработает отдебажся здесь
    // Console.WriteLine(tokenList[i]);
}
```

сработало?

Comment: да, тут правильно писали про одинарные кавычки. я получается строку с чаром сравнивал

Comment: @НикитаЕршов перепиши лучше на isDigit как посоветовал EvgeniyZ